# Long wait times in between view and controller, and Ajax calls

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

The issue is that the time it takes for the project to get to a controller is taking about a minute. Example: I go to index in "mycontroller", and the breakpoint at the start of index takes a minute or more to get activated.

The whole process then takes a few seconds to send the view,but any reload takes too long to be a viable wait time for the user.
Any Ajax call inside the view also takes a long time just to get to the function that I am calling.

This started yesterday(13-dec-21) and I have no idea what is causing the delay.
In case I am not making myself clear enough, I put a breakpoint at the start of my controller function (ActionResult). And it takes about a minute or more to be active. I then hit continue and in seconds the view is loaded. The issue is the sudden minute long wait in between the view and the controller. Same thing happens to any and all Ajax call.

Any help is appreciated.
This is the only filter I have active. and the response seems to have improveed after i made a some calls to [AllowAnonymous]

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)
            || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true))
        {
            // Don't check for authorization as AllowAnonymous filter is applied to the action or controller  
            return;
        }
        // Check for authorization  
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["key"] == null || HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login/");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like a timeout issue, is there a bad URL trying to load a resource somewhere?

Comment: None that I can detect, I hadn't even touched the code this two weeks, and noticed the problem this past Monday. i thought it may be an outdated ref, too many files in the files folder, a compilation issue, a merge, I even tried going back to October and the issue remained the same.
Will check for a timeout for some function I may be forgetting.

Answer (score 0):

You should check:

- Filters: `AuthenticationFilter`,`AuthorizeFilter`, `ActionFilter`... and any filters run before action is being excute.
- Depedencies contructor/ controller contructor for long-loading ones.

You can check pipeline of Asp.net [here](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/detailed-aspnet-mvc-pipeline).

Comment: Never added any fulters to my project, i checked, there is only de default function that's named "HandleErrorAttribute".

Comment: It's hard to check because i cant view your code.
you can check event register globaly in startup or global.asx, eg: some `AuthenticationEvent`...
You can check it slow because of high load or wait for other resource by view taskmanager.
And check log/console (when debug)/ Windows Events Viewer for any errors.

Comment: I added the only auth event filter I have on.